# can we use "Insanely bad" to describe an externally bad situation

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Can we use the adjective *insanely* to describe a condition which is extremely bad?.

Example: Job market is insanely bad.

Comment: It's informal, but correct.  In other words, don't put it in your thesis.

Comment: What kind of alternative are you looking for? More formal? More hip? Stronger? Milder? Funnier?

Comment: not sure why this question was down voted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Native English speakers will often use adjectives to describe something such as a job market that you wouldn't initially expect. This is more of a colloquialism than hard truth, and is also more informal.

In the example given, *Insanely* does make perfect sense to describe a bad job market - the underlying tone being that the job market is ***so*** bad that it could / would drive one insane.

Alternatives to the same affect:

> The Job market is utterly terrible
>
> The Job market is god awful
>
> The Job market is crazy
>
> The Job market is crazy bad
>
> The Job market is extremely bad
>
> The Job market is absurdly bad / job market is absurd.

Note that the word ***bad*** isn't always needed to get the point across that the job market is bad. You could just use a word that is inherently perceived as bad such as: 'the job market is crazy right now'

Try looking up synonyms for ***insanely*** under the meaning of ***madly*** or ***wildly*** for 100's more.